# FTP file download using Wget

Tags: wget

I am using the **wget** command for download FTP files, when i download the FTP file its showing error "Event not fount". Here i use the password like some below charater **!** so its showing this error

**bash: !@myipaddress: event not found**

Using wget command

```
wget -r ftp://username:password@ip/directoryname
```

Comment: Note: Default recursion depth is 5. You can use `-l inf` in addition to `-r` to remove the limit. Though you might want to look into `-m` (mirror).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can the same command by enclosing it with quotes:

```
wget -r 'ftp://username:password@ip/directoryname'
```

Comment: i use this command, but i have problem with my password special character like "!"

Comment: Enclosing the URL with quotes should solve it! Did you try it with quotes?

Answer (score 2):

When you type a word preceded by an "!", bash thinks you want to recall a previous command or "event". The message indicates no matching event was found in your recent command history. You can suppress the special meaning of ! by escaping it (`\!`) or quoting it with single quotes: `'!'`.

Comment: But My password have an "!", bash, so how could i use it